# PowerPoint Macro in a template

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am currently working on creating a template for a business presentation.

After the current client's name is written in the starting slide I want to be able to take it and place it on X amount of slides later created via a template, so that manual entry is almost completely reduced (this is a prerequest for the task).

Is it possible to create a macro so that it either edits the template slides after the needed information is written on the 1st slide or that it controls all the user created slides and labels afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is possible so long as the user can either install an add-in that you've written to do the job or open a file that you've saved as a PPTM rather than PPTX (ie, one with macros/vba included).